# How to fill polygon with different color than boundary?

Tags: c, opengl

I need to draw a polygon that has the boundary lines with one color and fill the  interior with another color.   Is there an easy way to do this ?   I currently draw two polygons one for the interior color and 1 for the boundary.  I think there must be a better to do this.   Thanks for your help.

```
       glColor3d (1, 1., .7);
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                glVertex3f(-0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex3f(-0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex3f(-0.7f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        glColor3d (.5, .5, .7);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                glVertex3f(-0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex3f(-0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex3f(-0.7f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();
```

Thank you everyone for answering my question.   I am fairly new to openGL and was looking for a simple answer to a simple question.  The answer appears to be not so simple and probably can take a semester worth of study.

Answer (score 3):

A more modern approach would be to implement this via geometry shaders. This would work for OpenGL 3.2 and above as part of the core functionality, or for OpenGL 2.1 with extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4.

This paper has all the relevant theory : [Shader-Based wireframe drawing](http://cgg-journal.com/2008-2/06/index.html). It also provides a sample implementation of the simplest technique in GLSL.

Here is my own stab at it, basically a port of their implementation for OpenGL 3.3, limited to triangle primitives:

Vertex shader: (replace the inputs with whatever you use to pass in vertex data an m, v and p matrices)

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in mat4 mv;

out Data
{
    vec4 position;
} vdata;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    vdata.position = projection * mv * position;
}
```

Geometry shader:

```
#version 330
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

in Data
{
    vec4 position;
} vdata[3];

out Data
{
    noperspective out vec3 dist;
} gdata;

void main()
{
    vec2 scale = vec2(500.0f, 500.0f); // scaling factor to make 'd' in frag shader big enough to show something
    vec2 p0 = scale * vdata[0].position.xy/vdata[0].position.w;
    vec2 p1 = scale * vdata[1].position.xy/vdata[1].position.w;
    vec2 p2 = scale * vdata[2].position.xy/vdata[2].position.w;

    vec2 v0 = p2-p1;
    vec2 v1 = p2-p0;
    vec2 v2 = p1-p0;
    float area = abs(v1.x*v2.y - v1.y*v2.x);

    gdata.dist = vec3(area/length(v0),0,0);
    gl_Position = vdata[0].position;
    EmitVertex();

    gdata.dist = vec3(0,area/length(v1),0);
    gl_Position = vdata[1].position;
    EmitVertex();

    gdata.dist = vec3(0,0,area/length(v2));
    gl_Position = vdata[2].position;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Vertex shader: (replace the colors with whatever you needed !)

```
#version 330

in Data
{
    noperspective in vec3 dist;
} gdata;

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

const vec4 wireframeColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
const vec4 fillColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

void main()
{
    float d = min(gdata.dist.x, min(gdata.dist.y, gdata.dist.z));
    float I = exp2(-2*d*d);
    outputColor = mix(fillColor, wireframeColor, I);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the fill mode between polygons, lines and points, using `glPolygonMode`.

In order to draw polygon lines in a different color you can do the following:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
draw_mesh( fill_color );
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
glPolygonOffset(-1.f,-1.f);
draw_mesh( line_color );
```

Line offset may be needed, because OpenGL doesn't guarantee the edges of polygons will be rasterized in the exact same pixels as the lines. So, without explicit offset you may and up with lines being hidden by polygons, due to failed depth test.

Comment: Isn't this approach the same as what I did ?   It looks like the mesh is being drawn twice.   Am I wrong ?

Comment: @tadpole. You wrote that you are drawing 2 polygons. I assume you cover the inner polygon area twice, what doubles the the load on the rasterizer. What I propose is to call the draw procedure twice, setting up different fill modes for GL.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing.   I updated the question to include my code.   I was hoping not to have to do that.  This is just a simple polygon, but the real code may contains hundreds to millions of polygons.

Comment: @tadpole. Oh, thats a much better-defined question :) In this case, consider reading http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/4884/pdf/imm4884.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this:

- the one you do at the moment (2 polygons, one a little larger than the other or drawn after)
- texture

to my knowledge there are no other possibilities and from a performance standpoint these 2 possibilities, especially the first one as long as you only color-fill, are extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see this answer:
[fill and outline](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/140906-Drawing-Triangles-That-are-outlined-and-filled)

> first draw your triangle using
>   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL) and use your desired color.
>   then draw the triangle again using
>   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE) using your outline color.