# webgl border color shader

Tags: border, webgl, shader, polygon

How do I write a shader to draw a polygon in solid color and it's border in a different color.

Basically I have a hexagons map in 3d and I need to be able to outline each hexagon with a black border, if user requests so. Would also be nice if I could control border width.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of attempt have you made?

Comment: I'm a total opengl/webgl newbie, so none so far.

Comment: Well, this question deals with [OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146216/how-to-fill-polygon-with-different-color-than-boundary)...

Comment: My best guess will be to check if pixel is on the line between 2 vertices, though I'm not entirely sure how to implement it in GLSL

Comment: Looks like the shader solution for that is for OpenGL 3.0, while I think WebGL uses OpenGL 2.0

Comment: The barycentric coordinates is actually quite an interesting read, thanks for sharing that. Unfortunately it draws border around triangles, which isn't exactly what I need.

Quite useful in learning how shaders work though, so was good for me in any case!

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head, one way would be to create a your hex with a 7th vertex in the center

```
   1---2
  /\   /\
 /  \ /  \
6----0----3
 \  / \  /
  \/   \/
   5---4
```

Add texture coordinates where point 0 has UV = { 0, 0 } and points 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 have UV coords { 0, 1 }.

Then have your shader choose a color based on V something like this

vertex shader

```
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
...

void main() {
  ...
  v_texCoord = a_texCoord; // pass texcoord to fragment shader
}
```

fragment shader

```
...
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform vec4 u_baseColor;
uniform vec4 u_borderColor;
uniform float u_borderThickness;  // 0-1
...
void main() {
  // make a value that's 0 if less than u_borderThickness and 1 if greater
  float mixAmount = step(u_borderThickness, v_texCoord.v);

  // choose the base or border color
  gl_FragCoord = mix(u_baseColor, u_borderColor, mixAmount);
}
```

I suppose you don't actually need 2 coordinates, you can just use 1 since U is irrelevant

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

var prg = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "a_position");
var vLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "a_v");
var baseColorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "u_baseColor");
var borderColorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "u_borderColor");
var borderSizeLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "u_borderSize");


var positions = [];
var vs = []

for (var ii = 0; ii < 6; ++ii) {
  var angle1 = (ii + 0) * Math.PI * 2 / 6;
  var angle2 = (ii + 1) * Math.PI * 2 / 6;
  positions.push(
    0, 0,
    Math.cos(angle1), Math.sin(angle1),
    Math.cos(angle2), Math.sin(angle2)
  );
  vs.push(0, 1, 1);
};

var positionBuf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
              new Float32Array(positions),
              gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, 
                       false, 0, 0); 

var vBuf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
              new Float32Array(vs),
              gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vLoc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vLoc, 1, gl.FLOAT, 
                       false, 0, 0); 


function render() {
  gl.clearColor(0,0,0,0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.useProgram(prg);
  gl.uniform4fv(baseColorLoc, [1, 0, 0, 1]);
  gl.uniform4fv(borderColorLoc, [0, 0, 0, 1]);
  
  var t = Date.now() * 0.001;
  gl.uniform1f(borderSizeLoc, Math.sin(t) * 0.5 + 0.5);
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 * 3);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}


render();
```

```html
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script id="vs" type="foo">
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute float a_v;

varying float v_v;

void main() {
  // PS: In a real WebGL app you'd probably need to multiply a_position by 
  // a matrix at a minimum

  gl_Position = a_position;
  v_v = a_v;
}
</script>

<script id="fs" type="foo">
precision mediump float;

varying float v_v;

uniform float u_borderSize;
uniform vec4 u_baseColor;
uniform vec4 u_borderColor;

void main() {
   float mixAmount = step(u_borderSize, v_v);
   gl_FragColor = mix(u_baseColor, 
                      u_borderColor, 
                      mixAmount);
}
</script>

<canvas id="c" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: Looks like this is way too advanced for me right now, off to read GLSL tutorials, then I'll get back to this :)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @gman, thanks for your answer and example. I'm a noob with shaders and I'm having difficulties to implement this in ThreeJS, so I created a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72632183/threejs-problem-implementing-non-threejs-shader
Any help will be greatly appreciated.