# ThreeJS: Problem implementing 'non-ThreeJS' shader

Tags: three.js, shader, border, shapes

I'm trying to use the shader from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764539/6736544 with a ThreeJS geometry, so far without success.

This is the original shader code from @gman:

```
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script id="vs" type="foo">
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute float a_v;

varying float v_v;

void main() {
  // PS: In a real WebGL app you'd probably need to multiply a_position by 
  // a matrix at a minimum

  gl_Position = a_position;
  v_v = a_v;
}
</script>

<script id="fs" type="foo">
precision mediump float;

varying float v_v;

uniform float u_borderSize;
uniform vec4 u_baseColor;
uniform vec4 u_borderColor;

void main() {
   float mixAmount = step(u_borderSize, v_v);
   gl_FragColor = mix(u_baseColor, 
                      u_borderColor, 
                      mixAmount);
}
</script>

<canvas id="c" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

This is my attempt:

```
<script>
    var vertexShader = `
        varying vec2 vUv;

        attribute float alpha;
        varying float vAlpha;
        
        attribute vec3 center;
        varying vec3 vCenter;

        void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            vAlpha = alpha;
            vCenter = center;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
    `;
    var fragmentShader = `
        //precision mediump float;
        uniform vec3 color1;
        uniform float color1Alpha;
        uniform vec3 borderColor;
        uniform float borderThickness;

        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying float vAlpha;
        varying vec3 vCenter;
        
        void main() {
            float u_borderSize = borderThickness;
            vec4 u_baseColor = vec4(color1, color1Alpha);
            vec4 u_borderColor = vec4(borderColor, 1.0);

            // This is where I get stuck. No idea how to get a correct 'v_v' value.
            float v_v = vUv.y;

        float mixAmount = step(u_borderSize, v_v);
        gl_FragColor = mix(u_baseColor, 
                            u_borderColor, 
                            mixAmount);
        }
    `;
</script>
```

See the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vuqarejz/

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Questions:

- Not sure what I'm missing, nor where the 'v_a' attribute is coming from.
- Maybe it is the way UVs are unwrapped?
- Maybe this is not the correct shader to use for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by tfoller in ThreeJS forum:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/unwrapping-a-custom-shapebuffergeometry/39565/4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).